# How do I click a dopostback target (aspx) with cURL after inital cURL post with a PHP script - complicated

Tags: php, curl

This is my first real cURL attempt and it may be the most complicated I could try.

First off, I am sending a correct GET request to an aspx page and retrieving the initial viewstate and eventvalidation; set up a cookiejar.

I then insert a value into one text field and master the submit button with cURL.

The page posts back to itself and now I have a link to click. I can prevent multiple options on link target. The link is a dopostback (ctl00\$cphMain\$dgHorses\$ctl02\$ctl00', '').

I need to click it to move on to next form.

Some code:

```
    $target2="ctl00\$cphMain\$dgHorses\$ctl02\$ctl00";
    // other variables all end up empty other than the viewstate and eventval
    $postfields2 = array();
    $postfields2["__EVENTTARGET"] = $target2;
    $postfields2["__EVENTARGUMENT"] = $argument;
    $postfields2["__VIEWSTATE"] = $viewstate3;
    $postfields2["__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"] = $generator;
    $postfields2["__EVENTVALIDATION"] = $eventValidation3;

    $postfields2["ctl00\$navBar\$navSearch\$txtSearch"] = $nav_search;
    $postfields2["ctl00\$navBar\$navJoin\$rblType"] = $join_type;
    $postfields2["ctl00\$navBar\$navLogin\$txtUserName"] = $user_name;
    $postfields2["ctl00\$navBar\$navLogin\$txtPassword"] = $password; 
    //$postfields2["ctl00\$cphMain\$dgHorses\$ctl02\$ctl00"] = '';


    $postit2 = http_build_query($postfields2);
```

Answer (score 0):

MY ANSWER: Simple, my curl did not have VERIFYHOST set to false. I am quite new to curl and assume I am having more trouble with it than reading and retrieving html. The page is very long and do not want to bore a reader with the depth of detail.